# How am I meant to display different elements on different pages?

Tags: blocks, theming

I'm coming to Drupal from more conventional MVC frameworks (Laravel, CakePHP, etc.)

In those frameworks, if I want a specific element (say, a form) to appear only on specific pages, then I basically do this:

- First, I register a route which maps a URL pattern (*e.g.*, `/path/to/form/page`) to a PHP controller method (*e.g.*, `FormController::display()`.
- Then, from `FormController::display()`, I return a view which includes the HTML for that form.

Things seem to be very different in Drupal, and it's really confusing me. I *think* I've figured out how this works in Drupal, maybe – but it's so bizarre (compared to what I'm used to) that part of me thinks it can't possibly be right.

So: can you please confirm (or deny) the following?

In Drupal, I should add *all* blocks that will *ever* appear in a particular region (on *any* URL) to that region (on the Structure > Block Layout page).

I should then configure the Visibility > Pages tab of each block to control which URL(s) it should appear on.

So, for a large site, the "Content" section of my Block Layout page could potentially include dozens of blocks. And it would therefore be misleading to think of the Block Layout view as a preview version of any given page on my site. It's just a listing of which blocks *might* appear in a region on any given page, depending on how the block placements are configured.

Is that basically right?

Comment: It's basically right.

Comment: _it would therefore be misleading to think of the Block Layout view as a preview version of any given page on my site_ Yes ,exactly that - the block layout interface is not intended to represent individual pages

Comment: Also worth noting you can do exactly the steps you mentioned at the top of your question (create a controller, route, display something) within Drupal. It sounded like you thought this wasn't possible. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-a-basic-controller

Comment: Yes and no. Blocks is just one concept in Drupal. You could also simply have a content type "Page" and on that page use a custom reference field "Form" to let editors place forms. You could even have a block reference field like the one provided by the [Block Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_field) module to let editors place blocks themselves. Or maybe have this block field inside one of many [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) types. Drupal is a Framework, you can make your own CMS from it. It basically depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Technically the core block layout is a display variant plugin. You can replace it with a different one like panels/page manager or you can even invent your own.